# Dropdown Menu not working, CSS issue, help please :)

Tags: wordpress, css

i'm not very good with css dropdown menus, and I cant get this to work, here's the code that I have for the css (the html is rendered by wordpress).

```
#top-container nav ul {

  text-align: left;

  display: inline;

  margin: 0;

  list-style: none;

  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);

  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);

  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);

}

#top-container nav ul li{     

  display: inline-block;

  margin-right: -4px;

  position: relative;

  padding: 10px 20px;

  background: #910051;

  cursor: pointer;

  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;

  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;

  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;

  -o-transition: all 0.2s;

  transition: all 0.2s;

}

#top-container nav ul li a{

    color: #fff;

}

#top-container nav ul li:hover {

  background: #53002e;

  color: #fff;

}

#top-container nav ul li ul {

  padding: 0;

  position: absolute;

  top: 45px;

  left: 0;

  width: 150px;

  -webkit-box-shadow: none;

  -moz-box-shadow: none;

  box-shadow: none;

  display: none;

  opacity: 0;

  visibility: hidden;

  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;

  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;

  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;

  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;

  -transition: opacity 0.2s;

}

#top-container nav ul li ul li { 

  background: #53002e; 

  display: block; 

  color: #fff;

  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;

}

#top-container nav ul li ul li:hover { background: #53002e; }
#top-container nav ul li:hover ul {

  display: block;

  opacity: 1;

  visibility: visible;

}
```

The last item has the dropdown, you'll see that it's not possible to click the dropdown item, I'm sorry to post such a noob question but my client is in a hurry.

Please use CTRL + F5 to refresh:

http://duolingua.cl/wordpress/

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this CSS to your site

```
ul.sub-menu.dropdown {
   z-index: 1;
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Happens to everybody at times :)

Answer (score -1):

in sub-menu class put "z-index: 1"

Comment: Can you add a little more detail?